# How can I define an array in Python with undefined keys?

Tags: python, arrays

```
searchindexnodes = []
searchindexnodes[1036592] = 'Apparel'
searchindexnodes[672123011] = 'Apparel'
searchindexnodes[165796011] = 'Baby'
```

This doesn't appear to be working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a dictionary for that:

```
searchindexnodes = {}
searchindexnodes[1036592] = 'Apparel'
searchindexnodes[672123011] = 'Apparel'
searchindexnodes[165796011] = 'Baby'
```

Answer (score 5):

I think a better solution would be to use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  If you wanted a list with empty elements you'd be creating a list with over 100,000,000 elements which would be a huge waste of memory.

```
searchindexnodes = {}
searchindexnodes[1036592] = 'Apparel'
```

Python implements searching quickly in dictionary data structures.  You could check if an element is present by doing something like

```
if 1036592 in searchindexnodes:
    print "It's there!"
```

Edit to iterate through the whole list you can do something like if you want the key and value

```
for key, value in searchindexnodes.items():
    print "{0} --> {1}".format(key,value)
```

otherwise what's below will loop through each key

```
for key in serchindexnodes:
    print key
```

Comment: Perfect! How can I iterate over searchindexnodes after?

Comment: @Shamoon: as any other iterable object: for i in searchindexnodes:

Comment: @Shamoon: See `items` and `iteritems` in the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items